# Image looking blurry on non-retina iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I know I should have two versions of my image, one standarad and one @2x but my app downloads a vast amount of content which i need to optimise. Im looking at using just retina images in my downloaded content and then seeing if there is an objective c way to take a graphic half it and make it none retina. using a retina image on my non retina ipad looks blurry.

Comment: Did you check the images having same name like image.png and image@2x.png ?

Comment: Please re-read, what im trying to do is see if theres a kind of coreimage way of resizing the uiimage so that i dont have to download two versions

Comment: Check image size, 2x is double of mormal image. If it failed remove Derived data. and delete app. Try again

Answer (score 0):

For images. You have to download separate images with your desired dimensions. For example Facebook timeline has separate image for user icon (e.g. 25x25). and For ever post having photo, a thumbnail is generated say it has dimensions (310x160). And then when a user clicks the image to view. It opens the original Image. Whatever dimensions it has. So, In your case. you have to download two images. One for your non retina and one for retina. You can use [Flicker API's](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) for that.

Note: You can skip this and continue with retina display because Non retina devices are rarely being used now. So, every one has retina device and app will work perfect with your existing scenario.